# Website content is overlapping for one user (might be an aspect ratio problem?)

Tags: html, css, wordpress, responsive-design

A client of my compagny just let us know that the content of the website we've been developping for his compagny is overlapping like crazy.
He sent us some screenshots, but so far we've not been able to reproduce the bug.
I'm sorry i can't share with you the code nor the screenshots because of compagny policy.
He then sent us this:

> User Agent String: "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:93.0)
> Gecko/20100101 Firefox/93.0"
>
> JavaScript screen.width x screen.height = 1280 x 720
> window.devicePixelRatio = 1.5 device pixels per CSS pixel Computed
> "true" screen.width x screen.height = 1920 x 1080
>
> JavaScript window.innerWidth x window.innerHeight = 1280 x 539
> window.devicePixelRatio = 1.5 device pixels per CSS pixel Computed
> "true" window.innerWidth x window.innerHeight = 1920 x 809
>
> JavaScript window.outerWidth x window.outerHeight = 1295 x 695
> window.devicePixelRatio = 1.5 device pixels per CSS pixel Computed
> "true" window.outerWidth x window.outerHeight = 1943 x 1043
>
> Tested in Firefox 55, Chrome 60, and Internet Explorer 11, all on
> Windows 7. Copyright © 2018 Jefferson Scher. Updated 6/7/2018.

Is there anything in there that is odd?
His aspect ratio seems off to me, but i don't know much about it.
We've been testing extensively today on multiple screen sizes, devices, os, browers.
So far we've only been able to reproduce PART of the bug (just one overlapping section) on a computer with a 125% aspect ratio (we tried 150% and 200% but nothing changed)

What are our options and how would you go about it?

Thanks in advance!

edit: The end note is that it was entirely triggered by the aspect ratio of the clients computer. For whatever reason when we tried to emulate his aspect ratio on our computers it wouldn work. When we got ahold on a computer that had a native 125% aspect ratio we eventually got the same results as him and got the issues fixed!

Comment: This isn't a programming question (and will probably be closed), but let me guess: he zoomed in the page (CTR + mouse wheel) - you can try it too.

Comment: Nope, one of the first things i've tried and nothing came out of it

Comment: Latest Firefox is 93, Chrome 95. IE is used only by your client. Support for Windows 7 ended on January 14 2020.

Comment: Oh so it may come from the fact that he's on windows 7??

Comment: Look at the end, he said `Tested in Firefox 55, Chrome 60, and Internet Explorer 11, all on Windows 7`

Comment: The end note is that it was entirely triggered by the aspect ratio of the clients computer. For whatever reason when we tried to emulate his aspect ratio on our computers it wouldn work.  When we got ahold on a computer that had a native 125% aspect ratio we eventually got the same results as him and got the issues fixed!